# error passing RSA public key from string to RSA * struct

Tags: c, openssl

I try to load a public RSA key to my program. I use openssl lib in C. The key is defined in header `crypt.h` file:

```
#define PUBLIC_KEY  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" \
                    "MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAuDcT2OiToi9edqil/3ha\n" \
                    "1MMrgqYvdYObRkb8C5SZtf8iv4LynuHi3hvEtybqFW84Uf2l3Dxuz3IWVp2v1C2f\n" \
                    "cUxwf+hFqL4Nt2Ww/XOKLtFXTSX/2fPYoelmLja2grHPSuFx6N4gtDUXRIGSYXIz\n" \
                    "c2GBx8lOiOP+qUguFmWZ9E0GiMLvh4XUQUzTGr4ZNNoc5LODdO0g7beFFqhntt9w\n" \
                    "EKdceGQtA7Zyt5l13x0lj+RONdPJkDFZrNGdqDwNUSog9mufpvR1P2UW09pC+lzy\n" \
                    "z32P+w0U3Za4zv4Btis9ky16vaqdN/KlDWJRt+4W9TQSAL0x9w708OQr0Sf2CXNq\n" \
                    "EobSLZ/aybe75yQmzFqmn10X+NuwTtJkArIKK7JONCBSxjohQmTZw0U497TCEHia\n" \
                    "itzgsHNLf1of31G/3GK5rCkm9fl39nnrg0yJi1cONTDjSHzKlrPhA584jFRD0CIO\n" \
                    "VNHYgsVLuFQuJ0WkZON8uEZELXN1ZyWnmPXH8wSwxjud65JD4JSQornCXorBMfxd\n" \
                    "DFEeeNk8tjgPMaCTLFNP/gfVDzkvcct9RoC8uZxHk8zgrGOwuxOZ/ZyihE7M8v0i\n" \
                    "+VwG9iMrPl8W3+KqunIt/FB4Le1vJ0yYorK64DRNdeMAIsYq2iFWO3GXNsX631/K\n" \
                    "EuZJS8tGNhK9dF5umo0GceUCAwEAAQ==\n" \
                    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
```

The RSA key is supposed to be saved in `RSA *` structure. I use a global variable for that.

```
RSA *rsaPubkey;
```

The `main()` calls a function that will take `PUBLIC_KEY` and pass it to `rsaPubkey`. The function is shown bellow:

```
#include "crypt.h"

int EVP_PKEY_get_type(EVP_PKEY *pkey) {
    if (!pkey)
        return EVP_PKEY_NONE;

    return EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type);
}

int PublicRSAKeyToStruct(const char *pubKey) {
    BIO* bio;
    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pubKey, (int)sizeof(pubKey));
    if (bio == NULL) {
        printf("bio");
        return -1;
    }

    EVP_PKEY* pkey;
    PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bio, &pkey, NULL, NULL);
    if (pkey == NULL) {
        printf("pkey");
        return -1;
    }

    int type = EVP_PKEY_get_type(pkey);
    if (type != EVP_PKEY_RSA && type != EVP_PKEY_RSA2) {
        printf("get type");
        return -1;
    }

    rsaPubkey = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    if (rsaPubkey == NULL) {
        printf("pubkey");
        return -1;
    }

    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    BIO_free(bio);
    return 0;
}
```

We call the function like that:

```
status = PublicRSAKeyToStruct(PUBLIC_KEY);
if (status == -1) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

My problem is that the `PublicRSAKeyToStruct()` function throws me the bellow user defined error:

```
get type
```

This means that we failed to pass `EVP_PKEY_get_type()`. I can't understand why this happen though. I have also no clue  if the problem is on the previous steps.

Comment: What is the value of `type` when the error occurs?

Comment: @Alden it's zero (0). So there is a failure somewhere?

Comment: @GuyL: don't do that. The data shown IS in PUBKEY=SPKI format and is NOT in RSA PUBLIC KEY (raw PKCS1) format.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PEM_read call failed because the BIO you gave it doesn't access the correct data, but you didn't check the return value, and you didn't initialize `pkey` so even though it's not valid your `pkey == NULL` check doesn't catch it. As described in the man page on your system (unless Windows) or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html) the second argument to `BIO_new_mem_buf` must either be the number of bytes in the buffer or -1 if buffer contains a null-terminated C string -- and a string literal like yours does yield a null-terminated string so -1 is suitable -- but `sizeof(apointer)` is neither of these.

The remainder of your code is correct and works fine if you give it a valid `EVP_PKEY*`.

Comment: I chagned it to `bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pubKey, -1);`. Now it works. Please add it in your answer. Also add the reference to https://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_new_mem_buf that suggest to add `-1` in second parameter. Change this so the others can understand it. Either way I'll accept your answer. (please add those infos).

Comment: @GeorgeGkas: I prefer not to reference linux.die.net for things that vary from version to version and OpenSSL does vary in many areas though not AFAIR for memBIO, so I used my preferred style instead. Yes, if you have a private key in one of the several PEM formats OpenSSL uses, `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` will read it. Note that (unlike publickeys) privatekeys are often password-encrypted, and if so your call should provide either the password itself or a callback that gets the password.